# Python : Connect android to python server

Tags: python

I am trying to connect my android to my python server on my machine. Both are on the same network. When I use "telnet (address) 5555" on my windows machine (same machine as server) , it works. But how to I connect my android to the server ? I have telnet for android , it tries to connect but it eventually says "connection timeout". So what is the problem ? I have checked the port , it is listening, so what do I do ? Keep in mind , that I am like 30 minutes in socket programming , so sorry if the answer is very obvious.

And another question is : what would I need to do , if I wanted machines of different networks to be able to connect to my server ?

Thank you , here is the code.

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import *

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((host,port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(5)
print('Waiting for a connection.')

def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode('Type your info: '))
    reply = ''
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        reply += data.decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        if '\n' in data.decode('utf-8'):
            conn.sendall('Out:' + reply.encode('utf-8'))
            print('Out:' + reply.encode('utf-8'))
            reply = ''
    conn.close()

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()

    print('connected to: ' + str(addr[0]) + ':'+str(addr[1]))
    start_new_thread(threaded_client,(conn,))
```

Comment: Main question solved. I had to forward the ports in my router.

Answer (score 1):

```
host = socket.gethostname() port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
```

Most likely is trying to bind to the loopback interface or to another interface which might be a virtual interface or just not connected to your network.
This will show up in netstat as :localhost or 127.0.0.1 or whatever your computer name is, or some local IP address.

You should try

```
host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
```

By specifying "0.0.0.0" you are asking the OS to listen on all interfaces.